# There are 6 people in a competition where only 3 can win. What is probability a particular person wins?

Tags: probability

There are 6 people in a competition- A, B, C, D, E, F.

Only 3 will be winners.

So what is probability that a particular person, say A, is a winner.

My friend said that probability of A being winner is 50%. I thought they are wrong because there might be some application of permutations/combinations there, but I am confused.

Comment: Assuming all players are equally likely to win, it must of course be $\frac{1}{2}$: there are just as many winners as non-winners, so by symmetry there are just as many outcomes with $A$ being a winner as $A$ not being a winner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nothing have been mentioned regarding individual winning probabilities etc. it is assumed that everyone id equally likely to win and hence,
3 winners can be chosen from a collection of 6 peoples in ${6 \choose 3}$ ways. $A$ wins precisely when among the other 5 people exactly 2 are chosen to be winners. Thus the desired probability is $\frac{5 \choose 2}{6 \choose 3}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: And Brozovic's $\frac{\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}6 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}}$ is precisely the obvious 0.5!

Comment: So my friend is right it is 50%. I was confused about permutation/combination part. But it is same as (winners/total competitors)= 3/6 = 50% xD. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If the 3 winners are chosen uniformly at random, that is the same as choosing the 3 *non-winners* uniformly at random.

So the probablity of "A is a winner" must be the same as "A is a non-winner", because probablity doesn't care about what we *call* the three persons we choose.

But if those probabilities are equal and their sum is $1$ (because exactly one of the events is true in any case), then they can only be $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the first person is $A$:
$$P(A_1)=\color{red}{\frac16}$$
the second person is $A$:
$$P(A_2|A_1')=\frac56\cdot \frac15=\color{red}{\frac16}$$
the third person is $A$:
$$P(A_3|A_1'\cap A_2')=\frac56\cdot \frac45\cdot \frac14=\color{red}{\frac16}$$
Hence, the probability of $A$ being one of the three is:
$$\frac16+\frac16+\frac16=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be 1/6 X 100 which is about 16.66 % as the formula for probability is the `no of outcomes you want` which is 1 divided by the `total possible outcomes` which is 6 the three winners is just there to confuse you

Comment: There are THREE winners chosen. If there was only one winner chosen, then the probability would be 1/6.